# Grid of numbers that randomizes on click

Tags: c#

I'm making a game that involves finding and clicking on a number (0-9) in a grid that randomizes each time you click on the correct one.

I want to get it so that when you click on the correct number, the grid randomizes again. 
How would you do this?

Here's what it would kind of look like in the end:

[image: http://puu.sh/4jphx.jpg]

Comment: Please describe the exact problem that you're having.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're rendering an array of integers in order:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfNumbers.Length; i++ ) {
    // rendering here
    render(arrayOfNumbers[i]);
}
```

If thats the case.. just randomize the array after a successful click.. somewhat like this:

```
var rnd = new System.Random();
var arrayOfNumbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 9).OrderBy(r => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
```

Then you can just re-render (or let your game loop continue to render the array). Since the array has changed, your rendering will too.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you detect a click on the correct number (I hope you know how to do this) you simply randomize the array of numbers you're displaying in your grid:

```
//Fisher-Yates algorithm
Random generator = new System.Random();
int len = array.Length;
while (len > 1)
{
    len--;
    int k = generator.Next(len + 1);
    int temp = array[k];
    array[k] = array[len];
    array[len] = temp;
}
```